# CMake include_directories(/usr/local/include) leads to building errors

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake

My main.cpp is

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "aaa" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Test)

include_directories(/usr/local/include)

add_executable(Test main.cpp)
```

As long as I use `include_directories(/usr/local/include)`, cmake building will fail.
The building output is

```
[build] Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target Test
[build] [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o
[build] In file included from /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:80,
[build]                  from /usr/local/include/sys/wait.h:110,
[build]                  from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:66,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6607,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/string:55,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ios:42,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
[build]                  from /Users/liushijia/Desktop/x/main.cpp:1:
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/_types/_user32_timeval.h:32:9: error: 'user32_time_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_time_t'?
[build]    32 |         user32_time_t           tv_sec;         /* seconds */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_time_t
[build] In file included from /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:81,
[build]                  from /usr/local/include/sys/wait.h:110,
[build]                  from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:66,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6607,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/string:55,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ios:42,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
[build]                  from /Users/liushijia/Desktop/x/main.cpp:1:
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/_types/_user64_timeval.h:32:9: error: 'user64_time_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_time_t'?
[build]    32 |         user64_time_t            tv_sec;        /* seconds */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_time_t
[build] In file included from /usr/local/include/sys/wait.h:110,
[build]                  from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdlib.h:66,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/cstdlib:75,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:41,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6607,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/string:55,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ios:42,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
[build]                  from /Users/liushijia/Desktop/x/main.cpp:1:
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:344:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   344 |         user64_long_t   ru_maxrss;              /* max resident set size */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:345:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   345 |         user64_long_t   ru_ixrss;               /* integral shared memory size */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:346:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   346 |         user64_long_t   ru_idrss;               /* integral unshared data " */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:347:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   347 |         user64_long_t   ru_isrss;               /* integral unshared stack " */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:348:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   348 |         user64_long_t   ru_minflt;              /* page reclaims */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:349:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   349 |         user64_long_t   ru_majflt;              /* page faults */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:350:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   350 |         user64_long_t   ru_nswap;               /* swaps */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:351:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   351 |         user64_long_t   ru_inblock;             /* block input operations */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:352:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   352 |         user64_long_t   ru_oublock;             /* block output operations */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:353:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   353 |         user64_long_t   ru_msgsnd;              /* messages sent */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:354:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   354 |         user64_long_t   ru_msgrcv;              /* messages received */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:355:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   355 |         user64_long_t   ru_nsignals;    /* signals received */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:356:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   356 |         user64_long_t   ru_nvcsw;               /* voluntary context switches */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:357:9: error: 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   357 |         user64_long_t   ru_nivcsw;              /* involuntary " */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:363:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   363 |         user32_long_t   ru_maxrss;              /* max resident set size */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:364:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   364 |         user32_long_t   ru_ixrss;               /* integral shared memory size */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:365:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   365 |         user32_long_t   ru_idrss;               /* integral unshared data " */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:366:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   366 |         user32_long_t   ru_isrss;               /* integral unshared stack " */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:367:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   367 |         user32_long_t   ru_minflt;              /* page reclaims */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:368:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   368 |         user32_long_t   ru_majflt;              /* page faults */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:369:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   369 |         user32_long_t   ru_nswap;               /* swaps */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:370:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   370 |         user32_long_t   ru_inblock;             /* block input operations */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:371:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   371 |         user32_long_t   ru_oublock;             /* block output operations */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:372:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   372 |         user32_long_t   ru_msgsnd;              /* messages sent */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:373:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   373 |         user32_long_t   ru_msgrcv;              /* messages received */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:374:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   374 |         user32_long_t   ru_nsignals;    /* signals received */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:375:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   375 |         user32_long_t   ru_nvcsw;               /* voluntary context switches */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] /usr/local/include/sys/resource.h:376:9: error: 'user32_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
[build]   376 |         user32_long_t   ru_nivcsw;              /* involuntary " */
[build]       |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build]       |         user_long_t
[build] In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:44,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6607,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/string:55,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ios:42,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
[build]                  from /Users/liushijia/Desktop/x/main.cpp:1:
[build] /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h: In constructor '__gnu_cxx::__stoa(_TRet (*)(const _CharT*, _CharT**, _Base ...), const char*, const _CharT*, std::size_t*, _Base ...)::_Save_errno::_Save_errno()':
[build] /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:63:34: error: 'errno' was not declared in this scope
[build]    63 |         _Save_errno() : _M_errno(errno) { errno = 0; }
[build]       |                                  ^~~~~
[build] In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6607,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/string:55,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ios:42,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
[build]                  from /Users/liushijia/Desktop/x/main.cpp:1:
[build] /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:45:1: note: 'errno' is defined in header '<cerrno>'; did you forget to '#include <cerrno>'?
[build]    44 | #include <cerrno>
[build]   +++ |+#include <cerrno>
[build]    45 | 
[build] In file included from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:44,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/basic_string.h:6607,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/string:55,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/bits/ios_base.h:41,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ios:42,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ostream:38,
[build]                  from /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/iostream:39,
[build]                  from /Users/liushijia/Desktop/x/main.cpp:1:
[build] /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h: In destructor '__gnu_cxx::__stoa(_TRet (*)(const _CharT*, _CharT**, _Base ...), const char*, const _CharT*, std::size_t*, _Base ...)::_Save_errno::~_Save_errno()':
[build] /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:64:30: error: 'errno' was not declared in this scope
[build]    64 |         ~_Save_errno() { if (errno == 0) errno = _M_errno; }
[build]       |                              ^~~~~
[build] /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:64:30: note: 'errno' is defined in header '<cerrno>'; did you forget to '#include <cerrno>'?
[build] /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h: In function '_Ret __gnu_cxx::__stoa(_TRet (*)(const _CharT*, _CharT**, _Base ...), const char*, const _CharT*, std::size_t*, _Base ...)':
[build] /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:84:16: error: 'errno' was not declared in this scope
[build]    84 |       else if (errno == ERANGE
[build]       |                ^~~~~
[build] /usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/include/c++/11/ext/string_conversions.h:84:16: note: 'errno' is defined in header '<cerrno>'; did you forget to '#include <cerrno>'?
[build] make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
[build] make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/all] Error 2
[build] make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Test.dir/rule] Error 2
[build] make: *** [Test] Error 2
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Error Type 1:

> 'errno' was not declared in this scope string_conversions.h(45, 1):
> 'errno' is defined in header ''; did you forget to '#include
> '?

string_conversions.h is a GNU extension to the Standard C++ Library but not written by me. As I checked the code, it had included cerrno in the header already.

Error Type 2:

> 'user32_time_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_time_t'?
>
> 'user64_time_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_time_t'?
>
> 'user64_long_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'user_long_t'?
>
> identifier "user32_long_t" is undefined

CMake 3.22.1; GCC 11.2.0; MacOS 12.1

I have no clue about how to solve these problems. I would be more than grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: I doubt this is related to cmake, and I suspect gcc wouldn't work if you tried this same compilation without cmake.  Out of curiosity, why are you adding this directory manually?

Comment: "The patient says, 'Doctor, it hurts when I do this.' / The doctor says, 'Then don't do that!'" ― Henny Youngman

Comment: It looks like you're forcing Clang to use GCC's standard headers which should never be expected to work.

Comment: @StephenNewell Yes gcc also cannot work without cmake. I don't know what's wrong with my setup and have posted another question. / I have to add this directory manually in one of my projects, or it cannot find the files needed. Last month, this worked well. I don't know what happened. (⑉꒦ິ^꒦ິ⑉)

Comment: @AlexReinking Then could you tell me how I should use gcc?